# How to count permanent connections to IIS FTP server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp

Whitc PerfMon counter show number of connections to server.
OS - Windows 2008 R2. IIS + FTP.

Comment: I find it. Its name is "Microsoft FTP Service".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no permanent connections to FTP and in perfmon you will only see current connections.  I would suggest you use something like this script to generate FTP reports from the logs (requires logparser):

```
@echo off

set LOGPATTERN=u_ex*.log

logparser.exe "SELECT DISTINCT date,x-session INTO '%~n0.tmp' from %LOGPATTERN%" -i:w3c -o:tsv -headers:ON

if exist "%~n0.tmp" (
logparser.exe "SELECT date,COUNT(x-session) AS sessions INTO sessions.tsv FROM '%~n0.tmp' GROUP BY date" -i:tsv -o:tsv -headers:ON
del "%~n0.tmp"
)

set LOGPATTERN=
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any permanent connections to the FTP server (there shouldn't be) but you can monitor several counters related to the FTP service, including current connections, by adding those counters from the FTP Service performance object in perfmon.